# Special character (like omega and beta) string matching in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, regex, jquery-mobile, special-characters

I am having difficulty with an application I am writing using PHP. The application's purpose is an open-source learning game with touchscreen support (using jQuery mobile). The game was working fine with a strcasecmp() comparing entries in the database with the selected answers (the users never enter data themselves, they only select from choices, so there is no input sanitization issue since the choices come direct from the database). However, when I added the ability to include special characters such as Ω and β, the strcasecmp() no longer worked. Naturally, I assumed the function would not be able to compare such symbols. After intensive research, I tried preg_match and mb_ereg_match, and while they worked fine for the regular questions, again, they wouldn't correctly match the questions with the special characters in them. Right now, here is what I have to compare the selected choice with the database entry:

```
$selAnswer = $_POST['mainanswer'];//asign from POST form

if (mb_ereg_match($selAnswer, $_SESSION['right']) == TRUE) //if the choice matches the right answer 
{
    //do right answer operations
}
else //if the question does not match
{
   //do wrong answer operations
}
```

So again, it works fine with regular strings, but not with the special characters. Is there anything that I can do to be able to match these characters successfully? One of the use cases is for a chemistry class, and they would definitely need to be able to add special characters such as omega and beta, etc. I appreciate any help anyone might be able to give.

**UPDATE:**

Since posting the entire game code would be extremely long, for everyone's reference, the general process is this: a simple HTML form submits questions to a MySQL database. Special characters are inserted using a customized version of TinyMCE that only allows formatting of bold, underline, italic, and special characters. An example of the way that it looks in the database is this:

```
&beta; is the right answer
```

So, once the data is in the database, the game code selects a random question and presents the one right answer and four wrong. If the selected answer and the database answer match, they are given a point. The game is made touch-friendly by jQuery mobile, but that is the only special thing about the code. The rest is just generic PHP/JS hand written in TextWrangler.

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

```
<?php

$special = "Ω and β";
$right_answer = "Ω and β";

//Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal. 
if (strcasecmp($special, $right_answer) == 0) {
    echo "You're right!";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, try again";
}

?>
```

and got this:

> You're right!

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think I might be seeing what's going wrong. I tried out your code, and it worked, but my text editor (TextWrangler) warned me that some characters wouldn't save, and that I had to switch to UTF-8. So, I let it change that, and uploaded it to my host, and sure enough it works just like yours did. I tried converting my PHP file (code above) to UTF-8, but the matching still did not work correctly. Perhaps I need to convert the entire project. Is there any specific way I should do this aside from using the text editor to do so? Also, I am posting the way my program works below.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
<?php

$database_answer = "Ω and β"; // <-- $grap correct answer from from mysql
$user_answer = "Ω and β";  // <-- make $user_answer the correct answer
// display hex representation of both strings
printf("%s<br>%s", bin2hex($database_answer), bin2hex($user_answer));

?>
```

- retrieve $database_answer from your database (mysql?) of correct answers

The above code should display exactly the same hex-string, if not, you have an encoding problem somewhere. You could start by ensuring that the character set for your database is set to UTF-8.

Comment: Yup, it's a MySQL DB. I tried this and indeed, the hex-strings are not the same. I got ceb26574617a6f6964 from the database and 26626574613b6574617a6f6964 from the selected answer, even though they appear identical when selecting. I looked into the database, and I see under "Collation" in the list of tables that it has "latin1_swedish_ci" listed for each table. Would this be what to change or would the setting lie elsewhere? In "information schema" under "character_sets": I assume this is just what the database is capable of supporting? Also, if I fix the db, should I mod the code in any way?

Comment: ceb26574617a6f6964 is correct UTF-8. If your database is producing that then no problem there. Is your HTML page set to UTF-8? <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: also: <form action="check_answers.php" accept-charset="utf-8">

Comment: I have HTML5 coding (jQuery mobile) so I'm using <meta charset="UTF-8">, should I go with the longer version instead? Also, I spoke with my professor about this, and he mentioned that it may be better to assign a "flag" of sorts to the correct answer in the database. In this way, I wouldn't have to do string comparison at all. This is also good because I may use pictures rather than text as "correct answers." Would you have any recommendations as to how I would go about "flagging" the correct answer? I assume a Boolean session variable at one point or another would work, or something like it.

Answer (score 0):

if your database is designed like so:

```
QuestionNumber    |    Answer
-------------------------------
 1                |      3
 2                |      1
 3                |      4
 4                |      2
 5                |      4
```

your HTML:

```
<select name="question1">
    <option value="1">α</option>
    <option value="2">β</option>
    <option value="3">γ</option>
    <option value="4">Ω</option>
</select>
```

That way, only the number '4' is sent to the server, as opposed to the answer 'Ω'. Then you would only have to compare numbers.

Comment: Thank you! That helped me to think of how to make the comparison non-reliant on content, which is what we were actually going for anyways, so character encoding is less of an issue. I do want to address it eventually as I'm sure it helps for everything to be in place (especially if we release our code and it needs internationalized, etc.), but for now, we have the functionality we needed. Thank you so much for your help with everything. I definitely learned a lot through our discussions! I would vote up your answer, but I'm new so I can't yet, but again, thanks!

Comment: i'm so glad it's working for you, all the best with your project!